# How to arrange a list in new order in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list which I am getting as a response from an API:

```
mylist = ['Production Name', 'Receipe Name', 'Cp', 'Target Thickness', 'Average Thickness', '2 Sigma',
      'Maximum Thickness', 'Minimum Thickness', 'Out of Limits', 'Variation Coefficient', 'Web Width', 'Length',
      'Roll Number', 'Roll Stop Time', 'Roll Start Time', 'Tics', 'Cycle Time', 'Mold Time', 'Open Time', 'Close Time']
```

Items inside the list are not fix at a particular index and they keep on changing. There are few items which I have to arrange in a particular order like a below list:

```
req_list = [ 'Receipe Name', 'Production Name', 'Roll Number', 'Roll Stop Time', 'Roll Start Time', 'Target Thickness', 'Average Thickness', '2 Sigma',
'Maximum Thickness', 'Minimum Thickness', 'Out of Limits', 'Variation Coefficient', 'Cp', 'Web Width', 'Length' ]
```

Extra items like `'Tics', 'Cycle Time', 'Mold Time', 'Open Time', 'Close Time'` then can be stored after `Length`

So the final list will look like:

```
req_list = [ 'Receipe Name', 'Production Name', 'Roll Number', 'Roll Stop Time', 'Roll Start Time', 'Target Thickness', 'Average Thickness', '2 Sigma',
          'Maximum Thickness', 'Minimum Thickness', 'Out of Limits', 'Variation Coefficient', 'Cp', 'Web Width', 'Length', 
          'Tics', 'Cycle Time', 'Mold Time', 'Open Time', 'Close Time' ]
```

How can I do this.?

Comment: Will the API response always include all the items that are in the fixed order list?

Comment: @Barmar Yes. Those items will always be there plus there will some extra items which we have to add at the end of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my example, I used `random.shuffle` to simulate `mylist`.

Create a `set`, use a list-comprehension to check whether the element in the set.

Try code below:

```
import random

mylist = ['Production Name', 'Receipe Name', 'Cp', 'Target Thickness', 'Average Thickness', '2 Sigma',
      'Maximum Thickness', 'Minimum Thickness', 'Out of Limits', 'Variation Coefficient', 'Web Width', 'Length',
      'Roll Number', 'Roll Stop Time', 'Roll Start Time', 'Tics', 'Cycle Time', 'Mold Time', 'Open Time', 'Close Time']

random.shuffle(mylist)

print(mylist)

req_list = ['Receipe Name', 'Production Name', 'Roll Number', 'Roll Stop Time', 'Roll Start Time', 'Target Thickness', 'Average Thickness', '2 Sigma',
'Maximum Thickness', 'Minimum Thickness', 'Out of Limits', 'Variation Coefficient', 'Cp', 'Web Width', 'Length']

tmp = set(req_list)

print(req_list + [i for i in mylist if i not in tmp])
```

Comment: Can you please explain the last step a bit more `print(req_list + [i for i in mylist if i not in tmp])`

Comment: @SAndrew Get the element which didn't exist in `req_list` and make sure the order of 
extra elements are the same as `mylist`.

Answer (score 1):

For this program you should use `random.shuffle(listname)`. Then `list = reqlist + randomlist`. In your case, I think it would look something like this:

```
import random             
extra_list = ['Tics', 'Cycle Time', 'Mold Time', 'Open Time', 'Close Time']
req_list = [ 'Recipe Name', 'Production Name', 'Roll Number', 'Roll Stop Time', 
'Roll Start Time', 'Target Thickness', 'Average Thickness', '2 Sigma',
'Maximum Thickness', 'Minimum Thickness', 'Out of Limits', 'Variation Coefficient', 'Cp', 'Web Width', 'Length' ]
random.shuffle(extra_list)
list = req_list + extra_list
print(extra_list)   
print(req_list)
print(list)
```

Comment: I think the question is essentially about how to extract `extra_list` from the API response.

Comment: I also don't see any requirement to arrange them randomly, just that they don't have to be in any specific order like `req_list`.